npm install progress bar not showing
I use a MacBook Pro m2, whenever i used to run the command "npm install something", i used to get a good looking progress/loading bar animation like this one below.
Loading bar i used have before
But but i dont know what recenlty i did to my mac, it stopped to show the good looking bar and i'm getting this kinda animation.
new animation I'm getting as a loading bar that i don't want
where i dont get the loading bar but i get those little lights blinking around, please help me get back the bar.
I tried to get the solution from chat gpt but not worked,

I tried uninstalling node and reinstalling it
set the npm config progress to true
set the terminal settings to default
unset CI

but none of these methods gave me the solution
help me to get back the default progress bar i used to have before

faced same issue and after lot of going through, only solution found that you just need to downgrade your npm to version 10.5.2 as from v10.6.0 progress bar is changed into spinter one.
downgrade code for that : npm install -g npm@10.5.2

Yes not terribly happy with the new progress bar. It has issues if using Windows ssh.

The progress bar in npm was temporarily removed.
if you need to see some sort of log you can use the verbose option
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer --verbose


you can follow the topic on github
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7597
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7425

You can fix this problem by installing previous version (<= 10.5) of npm:
npm install -g npm@10.5

